# How do I initialize values of a 2d array of structs?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, ppm

Im writing a ppm file with a 2d array of structs which act as the rgb values. The file writes, but when I try to pass the struct which contains the color value I want through my drawRect and drawCircle functions, the image does not draw with the dimensions I intended. The pixel values aren't written correctly into the array as well. I have separate functions that draw rectangles and circles, and createImg draws the entire image.

```
struct Color {
unsigned char red;
unsigned char green;
unsigned char blue;
};
int main() {

static Color image[LENGTH][WIDTH] = {};
createImg(image);
writeImg(image, 300, "torinCostales.ppm");

}

void createImg(Color image[][WIDTH]) {

//variables for red green and blue
Color red = { 255, 0, 0 };
Color green = { 0, 255, 0 };
Color blue = { 0, 0, 255 };

//dimensions and color value for the 4 different shapes
drawRect(image, 20, 15, 75, 150, blue);
drawRect(image, 100, 20, 100, 50, red);
drawCircle(image, 100, 200, 50, green);
drawCircle(image, 150, 150, 50, red);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//draws circle with given dimensions and sets array values to colorLevel
void drawCircle(Color image[][WIDTH],
int centerX, int centerY, int radius, Color colorLevel) {

for (int x = centerX - radius; x <= centerX + radius; x++)

   for (int y = centerY - radius; y <= centerY + radius; y++)
    
        if ((x - centerX) * (x - centerX) + (y - centerY) * (y - centerY) <= radius * radius)
        
            image[x][y] = colorLevel;
 }
        
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//draws the rectangle with given dimensions and colorLevel
void drawRect(Color image[][WIDTH],
int rectTop, int rectLeft, int rectHeight, int rectWidth, Color colorLevel) {

for (int col = rectLeft; col < rectWidth + rectLeft; col++)

    for (int rows = rectTop; rows < rectHeight + rectTop; rows++)
    
        image[col][rows] = colorLevel;
}

//writes the file
void writeImg(const Color image[][WIDTH], int height, const string fileName) {

std::ofstream imgFile;
imgFile.open("torinCostales.ppm");

//header
imgFile << "P3";
imgFile << "\n" << WIDTH << ' ' << LENGTH;
imgFile << "\n" << "255" << "\n";

//writes pixel values
for (int row = 0; row < LENGTH; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++)
        imgFile << static_cast<int>(image[row][col].red << image[row][col].green << image[row][col].blue) << ' ';
    imgFile << '\n';
}

imgFile.close();

}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what issue you have *with the code you shared*. There's no specific question, no statement of expected behavior, and no statement of what went wrong *that you attribute to this piece of code*. That makes it very hard to help you. Also, I strongly urge you to use things like `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: My array values are not initializing with the values I put into createImg. Im passing the struct that contains the values {255,0,0} for red into my drawRect and drawCircle functions. createImg is suppossed to draw 2 circles and rectangles. One of the circles is supposed to be centered at the points (100,200) in the array with a radius of 50. The array values in the image are supposed to be {0,255,0}, but the image outputs with the shapes in random positions and completely white instead of the colors I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this line is wrong:

```
imgFile << static_cast<int>(image[row][col].red << image[row][col].green << image[row][col].blue) << ' ';
```

Instead of casting each color to `int`, yous *SHIFT* the value of `red` by the number of bits specified by `green`, then by `blue`.

You want this instead:

```
imgFile << static_cast<int>(image[row][col].red)   << ' '
        << static_cast<int>(image[row][col].green) << ' '
        << static_cast<int>(image[row][col].blue)  << ' ';
```

Comment: @TorinCostales you are welcome! May be you could accept the answer to indicate that the issue is resolved?